# Как указать относительный путь к файлу Windows, Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java

```
s = new FileWriter("//link.txt");
```

Указываю так, пишет недопустимый путь к файлу? Как правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если файл в этой же папке то просто имя, если уровнем выше то - ../файл, если двумя уровнями выше - ../../файл

Answer (score 0):

Например файл называется - "text".
Если файл лежит в корне (возле pom.xml например) тогда путь будет такой:
"text"

Если в другой папке, тогда путь будет начинаться с src:
"src\main\java\day14\text".